How to change text selection in BasicText?
i'm trying to add Select All menu in SelectionContainer, i found this approach:
CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalTextToolbar provides CustomTextToolbar(LocalView.current)
    ) {
        SelectionContainer {
                BasicText(
                    text = text
                )
            }
        }
    }

inside CustomTextToolbar i have TextActionModeCallback field:

class TextActionModeCallback(
    var rect: Rect = Rect.Zero,
    var onCopyRequested: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    var onSelectAllRequested: (() -> Unit)? = null
): ActionMode.Callback {
    override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        requireNotNull(menu)
        requireNotNull(mode)

        onCopyRequested?.let {
            menu.add(0, MENU_ITEM_COPY, 0, android.R.string.copy)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM)
        }

        onSelectAllRequested?.let {
            menu.add(0, MENU_ITEM_SELECT_ALL, 3, android.R.string.selectAll)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM)
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun onPrepareActionMode(p0: ActionMode?, p1: Menu?): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        when (item!!.itemId) {
            MENU_ITEM_COPY -> onCopyRequested?.invoke()
            MENU_ITEM_SELECT_ALL -> onSelectAllRequested?.invoke()
            else -> return false
        }
        mode?.finish()
        return true
    }

    override fun onDestroyActionMode(p0: ActionMode?) {

    }
}

and i set callbacks inside CustomTextToolbar's showMenu, but the thing i faced is that SelectionContainer invokes showMenu without onSelectAllRequested, so it's null and there is no "Select All" menu
I tried to pass onSelectAllRequested to TextActionModeCallback manually so it's allways not null, then "Select All" is visible but i don't know how to implement text selection in this way, so clicking it doesn't do nothing
